# How can I keep track of where commits came from once they've been merged?

Tags: git, branch, commit

My company does not maintain the repository with `git` (we effectively use CVS), but I keep a repo locally for my own sanity.  In the past, I've wanted to bring up commits related to, say, `bug-report-abcde`.  I can grep through the commit messages to find `bug-report-abcde` and browse them.  Right now, I have an Emacs function hooked to provide the current branch name as a 'header' in the commit:

```
Title

Summary summary summary

Branch: bug-report-abcde
```

Thus my question is: is this the best way to find which branch was the original source of a commit, after the commit has been merged to another branch? Or is there a way to extract this information from `git` itself?

Comment: The Git designers made a decision early on to not track the type of information you seek.  You can find a lot of heated discussion in internet archives from 2005 about this issue.  There are ways to fake it somewhat if you are using a central server, but that doesn't seem to be the case for you.

Comment: @AndrewC If you can find a list message that supports this, "No can do" is an acceptable answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't track this information by design.

http://markmail.org/message/yfb5ihwddjmrstz6

```
So don't think of it as "git throws away branch identity" as much as
"git never cared about branch identity in the first place, and doesn't
think it's relevant."
```

Your branch name is just that, your branch name.  It can be literally anything you want.  Or you can not use a branch name, and be in detached head state.  Long term, only commit reachability is stored.

If you have information you want to track (like a Defect Number), then you need to include it in the commit message.

If you are using a central server you can setup a receive hook which logs the remote branch name information somehow (`git notes` for instance).  My company uses this.  I find it only quasi-useful (mainly if you want to yell at a program manager instead of the guy who wrote or pushed the code).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it provides a definitive source indicating that this is not possible in the general case.  A good solution for identifying *some* branch's commits -- ones where there was a merge commit -- can be found in @jthill's [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27435086/1443496).

Comment: For completeness - that only works for a subset of merge commits.  *if* they merged from a branch with a name that has meaning to you, and *if* the left the branch name in the commit message.

Answer (score 6):

```
merges-introducing() {
    # merges-introducing $introducing [$descendant]
    local introducing;
    if introducing=`git rev-parse $1`; then 
        shift
        git rev-list --ancestry-path --parents --reverse ^$introducing ${@-HEAD} \
        | awk '{seen[$1]=1} NR>1 && !seen[$2] {print $1}' \
        | xargs -r git show --oneline --no-patch
     fi
}
```

Finds the merges incorporating a commit from a merged history.

`git rev-list`'s `--ancestry-path` lists only the commits on the line of descent from the bottom commit (`^$introducing` here) to the top (default `HEAD`, your current checkout), `--parents` gives the parents for each of them, `--reverse` lists the commits oldest-first (so `$introducing` comes first), and the post-processing, the `awk|xargs`,  prints only merges whose first parent isn't on that ancestry path.

Unless someone's gone in and hand-edited the merge messages the subject lines for those commits will say the branch name and any source url of the relevant (and non-fastforward) merges, oldest first.

Comment: My apologies; the notification must have slipped through my inbox.  I'll try this out within a day or so.

Comment: This is a Bash function, yes?  Sourced in bash, this invariably shows only the most recent commit, regardless of whether it is actually related.

Comment: Take note that in this workflow, since I am the sole maintainer of the repository as far as git is concerned, there will hardly ever be any merge commits. See https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/14b9e070a37080b5dd7e for the log and note that master and a bugfix branch are on the same commit, but no merge commit was needed.

Comment: I fixed it showing the top commit when there's nothing to show otherwise.  Fastforward merges leave no trace in the commit graph, that's the whole point.  For fastforwards done in your repo in the last month I think there's enough recorded in the HEAD reflog to figure it out.

Comment: Unfortunately then this cannot be a full answer as it will necessarily miss such merges.  Useful information and clever tactic nonetheless, though.